# How to make adjacent items in Recycler View partially visible?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying implement `RecylerView` with big size images. However the adjacent elements of each item should appear just like `ViewPager` will do when we use `setPageMargin()` method. This `recylerView` should scroll vertically

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You should look into vertical viewpager.

Comment: Hi Govrav, I am trying implement recyler view with big size images. However the adjacent elements of each recyler item should appear just like viewpager will do when we setPageMargin() method. This recylerview will scroll vertically.

Comment: @ReazMurshed, I tried that as well and it has padding top issue. Please check below question and let me know if you any inputs on this. Thank you very much   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955101/how-to-add-page-margin-on-top-for-vertical-view-pager

Comment: I've edited your question with what you require. Please try to use correct description of what you want to achieve otherwise it wouldn't be possible for others to understand what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [RecyclerViewPager](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager) library, in `build.gradle` add:

compile 'com.github.lsjwzh.RecyclerViewPager:lib:v1.2.0@aar'

xml:

```
<com.lsjwzh.widget.recyclerviewpager.RecyclerViewPager
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    app:rvp_triggerOffset="0.1"
    app:rvp_singlePageFling="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

code:

```
RecyclerViewPager mRecyclerView = (RecyclerViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

// setLayoutManager like normal RecyclerView, you do not need to change any thing.
LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);

//set adapter
//You just need to implement ViewPageAdapter by yourself like a normal RecyclerView.Adpater.
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adpater<X>());

// That is all.
```

**Update**

Add this  `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` under build.gradle (project level) in `allprojects->repositories` block, your code should look like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: above library is not found, it is giving          ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.lsjwzh.RecyclerViewPager:lib:v1.2.0

Comment: allprojects {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
app module gradle:      implementation 'com.github.lsjwzh.RecyclerViewPager:lib:v1.2.0@aar'

Comment: use version 1.1.0 replace by this: 
implementation 'com.github.lsjwzh.RecyclerViewPager:lib:v1.1.0'